# API Gateway not passing event to lambda from console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I'm trying to call a basic lambda from my API Gateway console. The lambda has an input taken in by the event called `filterBy`.

I created a query string called `filterBy` however, when I try to invoke the lambda I get the error:

`{errorMessage: {'statusCode': 500, 'body': '{"msg": "KeyError(\'filterBy\')"}'}}`

Presumably because the piece of code in my lambda

`event['filterBy']` is not finding a filterBy in the event. What do I need to do so that I can get the filterBy in the event from the API Gateway console? I understand this is probably quite simple but I surprisingly cannot find anything about this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you see when you log `event` object in your Lambda? Does it have `queryStringParameters` or `pathParameters` keys? Also, how are you passing `filterBy` parameter to your Lambda function?

Comment: In the console I'm just passing in a filterBy=filter in the box that takes in query strings. From the lambda console, I can see the event object fine when I print it. I set the query string paramater to be filterBy in the API GW console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the integration type, approach can be vary.

**1.** Lambda custom integrations

Looks like you are trying to use [Lambda custom integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html). If that is the case you have to add a mapping template as below.

(under the `Integration Request -> Mapping Templates --> Add mapping template`)

```
{
     "filterBy": "$input.params('filterBy')"
}
```

Please refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/pass-api-gateway-rest-api-parameters/) article or [this](https://youtu.be/aQHK8XrQmSs) video for more info.

**2.** Lambda proxy integrations

If you are using Lambda proxy integration (either as [REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) or as [HTTP APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html)), then instead of `event['filterBy']`, you have to access the `queryStringParameters` first and then access the relevant query param.

```
event['queryStringParameters']['filterBy']
```

And another thing is: once you modify something in API GW, please make sure to deploy and wait some time before test. :)

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to add the mapping template through the CDK?

Comment: I haven't tried that with CDK. But I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68795584/3668866) would help you on that. Also pls check [LambdaIntegration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.LambdaIntegration.html) as well.